# Android Studio - ошибка "Cannot resolve symbol/method ..."

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-data-binding

В проекте в подключен биндинг. И по какой то причине, в последнее время Android Studio начал выдавать ошибки связанные с этим биндингом.

Если точнее, то *Cannot resolve symbol 'DataBindingUtil'*, везде где используется **DataBindingUtil**. И *Cannot resolve method 'getRoot()'*, везде где используется **getRoot()**. В импортах DataBindingUtil обозначен как неиспользуемый.

п.с. Заметил что это не только с биндингом связано. Иногда попадаются похожие ошибки в других местах. И все начинаются с фразы - *Cannot resolve symbol/method*.

Пример того как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Особенность ошибок в том, что компилятор о них ничего не говорит. Почти все классы заполнены ими, но при этом проект нормально собирается и все работает.

Подскажите, что мне предпринять, чтобы от них избавиться?

На данный момент уже пробовал делать Clear + Rebuild, потом Invalidate Caches. Переустанавливал Android Studio. Не помогает.

---

Здесь были довольно объемные gradle файлы, но я их удалил, потому что как оказалось не в них было дело. По крайней мере не напрямую.

Comment: у меня такое бывает, когда проект достаточно большой. Я так и не нашел способов решения, работаю с "красными предупреждениями"

Comment: Градл скрипт покажите.

Comment: @Suvitruf, добавил код gradle файлов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со временем количество подобных ошибок в проекте нереально возросло и все таки пришлось найти решение проблемы.

**Мне помогло следующее:**

1. Удаление папок *.idea* и *.gradle*. Это удобно сделать в режиме проекта.
2. Не закрывая проекта заходим в *File* и жмем *Invalidate Caches / Restart*.
3. Когда *Android Studio* перезагрузится и сделает все свои дела, жмем *Sync Project with Gradle files*.